# Overwrite the hash value (java)

Tags: java, arrays, junit, hashtable, hashcode

Can anyone give some help over here? :)

I am failing to pass this JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testInsert() {
    Hashtable <Boolean> h = new Hashtable <Boolean> (1000, PROBE_TYPE.DOUBLE_HASH);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        for (int j = 2000; j > 0; j--) {
            h.put(i + ":" + j, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my put method:

For the put method the value against the given key must be stored. If `loadFactor>maxLoad`, `resize()` (method to resize the array). If there is a key already, overwrite the value. New `Pair` item including (key, value) `findEmpty` (to find the next empty position in the array to store the pair). Call `findEmpty` with the hashed value of the key as the start pos for the search, `stepNum` of zero, and the original key.

```
public void put(String key, V value) {
    boolean isTrue = false;
    int size = 0;
    Pair aPair = new Pair(key, value);
    if (getLoadFactor() > maxLoad) { //if the maxLoad value is exceeded.
        resize(); //call the resize method.
    }
    if (hasKey(key)) { //if there is a key(position occupied).
        while (!isTrue) {
            if (size < max) { //if the size is less than the maximum size.
                if (arr[hash(key)].equals(key)) { //if the key already exists
                    aPair.value = value; //overwrite the value
                    isTrue = false;
                }
                size++;
            }
        }
    } else { //if the position is not occupied.
        int empty = findEmpty(hash(key), 0, key); //find the next empty position.
        arr[empty] = aPair; // stored in the empty position.
    }
    itemCount++;
}
```

`Pair` instances are stored (in an array). Check original key in case of collisions. Here is the `Pair` class:

```
private class Pair {
    private String key;
    private V value;

    public Pair(String key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

> `getLoadFactor()`: returns a double for the size
>   `maxLoad`: is a double = 0.6
>   `itemCount`:  the number of items stored in the array
>   `hasKey()`: returns a boolean true/false if there is a key or not
>   `private V find(int startingPosition, String key, int stepNumber)`
>   `private int findEmpty(int startingPosition, int stepNumber, String key)`
>   This is a hashtable `Hashtable<V>` 
>   I'm using an array `private Object[] arr`

Comment: What's happening in your `resize()` function?

Comment: Just posted it now.

Comment: What is your question? Do you need to write HashTable implementation?

Comment: As posted above, I am failing to pass the JUnit Test: testInsert, and I think this is a caused by a put's method bug. Can you help me pass the test?

Comment: Surely JUnit is giving you a stacktrace? What does it say? Which line/s of the code you have posted does it refer to?

Comment: No it doesn't. As you can see in the test its uses the put method, so I assumed the error is somewhere inside the put method.

Comment: You say your JUnit is telling you the test failed and is telling you no details about why it failed? Incredible. I’m not convinced you are using JUnit in the right way. Try [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And/or your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Hashtable;


public class Main <V>{

    private Integer max;
    private Object[] arr;
    private long itemCount = 0;
    private double maxLoad;

    public Main(int i) {
        this.max = i;
        maxLoad = 0.75;
        arr = new Object[i];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main<Boolean> h = new Main<Boolean>(1000);
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            for(int j=1000;j>0;j--) {
                h.put(i+":"+j, true);
                System.out.println(counter);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }



    private void resize() {
        Object[] oldArray = arr;
        max = max * 2;
        arr = new Object[max];
        itemCount = oldArray.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
            if (oldArray[i] != null) {
                Pair arPair = (Pair) oldArray[i];
                arr[i] = arPair;
            }
        }
    }

    public void put(String key, V value) {
        boolean isTrue = false;
        int size = 0;
        Pair aPair = new Pair(key, value);
        if (getLoadFactor() > maxLoad) { // if the maxLoad value is exceeded.
            resize(); // call the resize method.
        }
        int index = hasKey(key);
        if (index != -1) { // if there is a key(position occupied).
            ((Pair<V>)arr[index]).value = value;
        } else { // if the position is not occupied.
            int empty = findEmpty(hash(key), 0, key); // find the next empty
                                                        // position.
            arr[empty] = aPair; // stored in the empty position.
        }
        itemCount++;
    }

    private int findKey(String key) {
        int index = 0;
        for (Object obj  : arr) {
            Pair pair = (Pair) obj;
            if(pair!= null && pair.key.equals(key))
                return index;

            index++;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private double getLoadFactor() {

        return (double)itemCount / max;
    }

    private int findEmpty(int hash, int i, String key) {
        int j = 0 ;
        for (Object obj  : arr) {
            Pair pair = (Pair) obj;
            if(pair != null){
                j++;    
            }else{
                return j;
            }

        }
        return j;
    }

    private int hash(String key) {
        return key.hashCode();
    }

    private int hasKey(String key) {
        int counter = 0 ;
        for (Object obj  : arr) {
            Pair pair = (Pair) obj;
            if(pair != null && pair.key.equals(key)){
                return counter;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return -1;
    }



    private class Pair<V> {
        private String key;
        private V value;

        public Pair(String key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to add some comment. There are some methods that I don't have so I wrote my code. Also there is an recursive call in resize() method, that recursive call loops infinite.

Comment: Also this is not Hashtable implementation and the algorithm is too slow 1m  record is counting slowly. I tried to fix other stuff.

Comment: Appreciate your help but, If the key already exists then its value should be overwritten.  The resize() method is okay i don't need anything there.

Comment: Ok you can find the location of the key, then replace the value. I will write that code in a minute

Comment: Thank you, do you see anything else that will prevent the test to pass? :

Comment: the first thing I notice is what happens when the key is already in the
hash table  - that doesn't mean it is in the position returned by the
hash function, because there might have been a collision.
So you could  make a method like find that returns the index of a pair,
rather than its value, then that would tell you where the existing pair is.

Comment: In resize there is a recursive call and that's dangerous, maybe you can check there. Also the algorithm is slow you can check from counter in the console. It continues until 10 minutes

Comment: I guess the best thing is return index when hasKey method is called

Comment: Ok you can find the location of the key, then replace the value. I will write that code in a minute  ---> can you please write this code

Comment: ((Pair<V>)arr[index]).value = value;The type Hashtable<V>.Pair is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <V>

Comment: V will be replaced with boolean so that is not a problem I guess

Comment: Let's return to the java.util.List<E>, in an actual invocation, such as List<Integer>, all occurrences of the formal type parameter <E> are replaced by the actual type parameter <Integer>. With this additional type information, compiler is able to perform type check during compile-time and ensure that there won't have type-casting error at runtime. (https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaGeneric.html)

Comment: thanks fro your help. the test still fails though, i can not figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is an infinite `while` loop in your `put` method. First, the loop will only terminate if you set `isTrue` to `true`, which you never do. Changing the assignment inside `if` to `isTrue = true;` *may* help, but only if you get in there. If `size` is greater than or equal to `max`, you never will no matter how many times through the loop, so it will still be infinite. Next, if understand correctly that `arr` contains `Pair` objects, `arr[hash(key)].equals(key)` will never be true, also keeping your loop from terminating.

There may be yet more bugs in there. Hope this gets you a step further.